# loading a file into an array, processing the second file using the data in the aray

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm in a cygwin environment on Windows 7.
I'm running an existing awkscript with the command:

```
awk -f awkscript datafile.txt
```

The awkscript reads & processes data in datafile.txt and one of the fields in datafile.txt is a code.

Example:    `f1|f2|f3|f4`

...where the f2 value is a code

I could hardcode the code and it's description in the awkscript into an array in a function and print out the description when I'm processing but that to me is a sloppy way.

An example of the data with the code & description is as follows:

```
111|Description of 111
222|Description of 222
333|Description of 333
```

...where 111 is the code and I want to print out "Description of 111"
I'll call this file `code-descr.txt`

Since the above file with the code & description will never change I would like to run the awkscript and have it read code-descr.txt into an array.

How do I add this to the command line: `awk -f awkscript datafile.txt`?
If I do not need to add anything to the command line, how do I always read code-descr.txt into an array when I run: `awk -f awkscript datafile.txt`?

Answer (score 6):

try

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"} 
     FILENAME=="code-desc.txt" { descr[$1]=$2 ; next }
      { for(i=1;i<=FS;i++) printf "%s|",descr[$i] ; printf "\n" ;} '  code-desc.txt datafile.txt
```

where

- `BEGIN { FS="|"}`  tells awk to use | as separator
- `FILENAME=="code-desc.txt" { descr[$1]=$2 ; next }` when parsing code-desc.txt, build array.
- for all other line, print description of field.

please note:

- respect order of file (code-desc.txt before datafile.txt),
- code between single quote can be put in an awk script,
- this will not work if you have a wrong code.

Comment: If you don't know the filename until run time, the idiom is `FNR == NR` (unless you know of another way).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `desc="code-desc.txt"; awk -v desc="$desc" 'FILENAME==desc {..}' "$desc"` is a solution for a run time filename.

Comment: @WalterA: True, but I meant when passing it as an argument following the command.